# trying to prove dot product definitions (algebraic and geometric) are equal, found inconsistency

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

Im trying to follow this proof
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9aomoLESkeI

The intention is to prove that the geometric and algebraic definitions of the dot product are equivalent.

The author does most of the proof using mostly coordinate notation ($<a_x,a_y,a_z>$), I wanted to simplify things by using vector notation ($\vec{A}$) until the very end and I found I cant do it, not sure why.

First I declare the law of cosines using the vectors $\vec{A},\vec{B}$.

I declare vector $\vec{C}$ to be

$\vec{C}=\vec{A}-\vec{B}$

So, law of cosines:
$$
|A|^2+|B|^2-2|A||B|cos(\theta)=|A-B|^2
$$

I expand the right hand side
$$
\require{cancel}
\text{Expand right side: }
|A|^2+|B|^2-2|A||B|cos(\theta)=|A|^2+|B|^2-2|A||B| \\
\text{simplify: }\cancel{|A|^2}+\cancel{|B|^2}\cancel{-2}|A||B|cos(\theta)=\cancel{|A|^2}+\cancel{|B|^2}\cancel{-2}|A||B|\\
\text{then: }|A||B|cos(\theta)=|A||B|
$$

Ok so thats a funny result that could only be true if $\theta$ is $0$

whats the meaning of this?

can somehow $|A||B|$ be transformed into $a_xb_x+a_yb_y+c_xc_y$? the proof on the video would suggest so, but i dont see how I can do that from 
$$
|A||B|= \sqrt{a_x^2+a_y^2+a_z^2}\sqrt{b_x^2+b_y^2+b_z^2}
$$

maybe im missing some simple algebraic trick?

Comment: $$|A-B|^2=(A-B)\cdot(A-B)=|A|^2+|B|^2-2A\cdot B.$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that, in general,

$$|A-B|^2 \neq |A|^2 + |B|^2 - 2|A| |B| \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

Instead, as stated in [Aretino](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/255730/aretino)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3558916/trying-to-prove-dot-product-definitions-algebraic-and-geometric-are-equal-fou/3558922#comment7317850_3558916), you have

$$|A - B|^2 = (A - B)\cdot (A - B) = |A|^2 + |B|^2 - 2A \cdot B \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

This shows it's only true when $A$ and $B$ are parallel, i.e., $\theta = 0$, as you found.

In a similar concept, consider the [triangle inequality](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Triangle_inequality) which says

$$|A + B| \leq |A| + |B| \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

Squaring both sides gives

$$|A + B|^2 \leq |A|^2 + |B|^2 + 2|A| |B| \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

In particular, the $2$ sides are not equal in general.

Comment: that's interesting. the two vectors do not seem to be presented as parallel in the proof on the video.

Comment: @JoaquinBrandan I haven't watched the video. However, my understanding of your question is that you are doing that expansion instead. As my answer states, it's not true in general, which is why you got the apparent contradiction that it can *only* be true if $\theta = 0$.

Comment: In the video its assumed that the vector opposed to $\theta$ is $C$ (opposed as the opposed side of the angle in a triangle) and that for any vector $C$ it must be true that $C=A-B$ (as dectribed here https://qph.fs.quoracdn.net/main-qimg-a5edfd35121e6cabd46fb767f73ca1a7.webp )

Comment: @JoaquinBrandan My point is, did the video at any time say my ($1$) equation was always true, i.e., $|A - B|^2 = |A|^2 + |B|^2 - 2|A| |B|$?

Comment: the video seems to imply that $|A - B|^2 = |A|^2 + |B|^2 - 2|A| |B|cos(\theta)$ is always true for any $\vec{A}$ and  $\vec{B}$ because the law of cosines says $|C|^2 = |A|^2 + |B|^2 - 2|A| |B|cos(\theta)$ and it will always be the case that $\vec{C}=\vec{A}-\vec{B}$. So no, the video does not use your equation $(1)$ because it also adds the cosine at the end of $(1)$

Comment: @JoaquinBrandan That part is correct. The issue is your expansion of $|A - B|^2$ is not generally correct.

Comment: i wish I could mark more than one answer as correct. thank you all

Answer (score 2):

$$ \require{cancel} \text{Expand right side: } |A|^2+|B|^2-2|A||B|cos(\theta)=|A|^2+|B|^2\color{red}{-2|A||B|} \\ $$

You should use $A=(a_x,a_y,a_z)$ and $B=(b_x,b_y,b_z)$then
\begin{eqnarray*}
\mid A-B \mid^2 &=& (a_x-b_x)^2+(a_y-b_y)^2+(a_z-b_z)^2 \\
&=&\mid A \mid^2 + \mid B \mid^2 \color{blue}{-2(a_xb_x+ a_yb_y+a_zb_z)}. \\
\end{eqnarray*}

Comment: I did, but shouldnt that mean that $|A||B|= 2(a_xb_x+a_yb_y+a_zb_z)$ somehow? how do you get to that?

Comment: When you expand each bracket you get three terms 
\begin{eqnarray*}
 (a_x-b_x)^2=a_x^2+b_x^2-2a_xb_x.
\end{eqnarray*}
Now regroup the terms ...

Comment: I did, I know I get that if I use the coordinate notation, however if i first use the  vector notation I end up with  $|A|^2+|B|^2-2|A||B|$, this means that $|A||B|= 2(a_xb_x+a_yb_y+a_zb_z)$, however given that $|A||B|= \sqrt{a_x^2+a_y^2+a_z^2}\sqrt{b_x^2+b_y^2+b_z^2}$ then $\sqrt{a_x^2+a_y^2+a_z^2}\sqrt{b_x^2+b_y^2+b_z^2}= -2(a_xb_x+a_yb_y+a_zb_z)$ and I dont see how that can be true. I hope that clarifies the question.

Comment: See the first equation in John Omelian's answer. $\mid . \mid^2$ does not expand like that.

Comment: Thanks, I hadnt noticed that it didnt expand like that. actually the expansion uses the dot product itself, so to expand in vector notation I actually have to do this proof first to then define the expansion in vector notation as using the dot product. thank you.